# Chrome RSS Viewer similar to Firefox where registration / external website is not required

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, rss, local

I've tried 8 different RSS viewers and each of them either force me to sign up for their RSS aggregator or redirect to some external website without signing up.

I'm looking for no external dependency (local only) rss reader and tracker in Chrome. Is there such a thing? or should I use Firefox for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Feedbro extension for Firefox, appropriately updated to support the new architecture. A quick search using The Google for "feedbro for google chrome" resulted in a solid indication that [Feedbro is available](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/feedbro/mefgmmbdailogpfhfblcnnjfmnpnmdfa?hl=en-GB) for that platform.

I suspect that there are many different tastes in how one wishes one's RSS feed reader to present the information. It was a difficult passage for me to locate one that satisfies my needs and Feedbro was it.

I cannot attest to your preferences and you may not like the appearance, but this program does state that no external interaction is required. This was accurate with my experience as well.

[image: feedbro for chrome]

Comment: This is great! One thing I'm using the RSS feed for is to follow along AWS updates and Feedbro's Rule system is perfect. Thank you so much.